# NAS setup help w/ home

Tags: networking, router, external-hard-drive, nas, modem

so I'm not super experienced with Networking, so I may have already committed some Faux-pas in my setup, so please bear with me;

I have a HDD connected to my modem (TC8715) that I'd like to use as a shared drive across my house. I also have a wifi router for wifi in the house (obviously)

The issue is, that My desktop PC is connected to the Modem directly in the basement, while my WIFI router is up on the 2nd floor. My PC can get to the HDD just fine, but my wife's laptop cannot see it over the wifi.

I'd like to avoid having to run more Ethernet cable up to the router, so I'm pretty against the idea of connecting the HDD and Desktop to the router.

Is there any way to conveniently have my router pick up the HDD on the Router and pass it along to wifi users

Answer (score 1):

According to the
[TC8715 User Guide](https://mediacomcc.custhelp.com/euf/assets/documents/modem%20user%20guides/Technicolor%20TC8715%20User%20Guide.pdf),
the disk should be connected directly to the router via a USB port:

[image]

The disk is available to all computers on the network.
In Windows Explorer, it should be detected as a device named `BRCM-LVG`:

[image]

Double-click `BRCM-LVG`to see the disk.

If you cannot see `BRCM-LVG` over WiFi, it is possible that your router is
wrongly configured to use the disk only on the wired network.
You will need to change this setting, which could possibly be separating
the wired and wireless in disjoint segments.

Comment: my whole issue is that i HAVE setup as above and i cannot see over wifi you provided the info i have already

Comment: Did you check router parameters as above?

Comment: no idea how to do this

Comment: Have you looked at what's available in your router's page on `http://192.168.0.1/admin`? The default username and password are `admin` and `password`. If you can't see anything, better call Support and complain.